# Efficiently updating a timer and checking condition is met in python

Tags: python, performance

Here's a simple script to play a sound every few minutes:

```
import pyglet
import time
from random import randint

music = pyglet.resource.media('input.wav', streaming=False)

def playSound():
    music.play()

counter = 0
random = randint(300,900)
prevTime = 0

while True:
    counter += time.time() - prevTime
    prevTime = time.time()
    if (counter>random):
        playSound()
        counter = 0
        random = randint(300,900)
```

Works as expected, but it uses 100% CPU. Is there a way I can make it more efficient? Is the way I've done it here the 'python' way of doing things?

Answer (score 3):

The approach depends on whether or not you need the script to do anything else whilst waiting. If it only has to play the file, then the follow approach should suffice:

```
import pyglet
import time
import random

music = pyglet.resource.media('input.wav', streaming=False)

def playSound():
    music.play()

while True:
    time.sleep(random.randint(300, 900))
    playSound()
```

[time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time.sleep#time.sleep) will suspend the execution of your script for the given number of seconds. As such it will not use any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `time.sleep(.1)` in the loop. Your loop is currently busy in that it is constantly updating current_time as fast as it can. Adding the `sleep()` call allows the CPU some breathing room to do other stuff.

Also, the `time.time()` logic could be improved so you only do the function call once (function calls are relatively slow in Python):

```
current_time = time.time()
counter += current_time - prev_time
prev_time = current_time
```

Or better yet, just maintain the start time and compare the difference (this assumes you properly initialize everything):

```
current_time = time.time()
if current_time - start_time > random_interval:
    play_sound()
    start_time = current_time
    random_interval = randint(300, 900)
```